# How to make a label of GUI PowerShell has same location in any display executed?

Tags: winforms, powershell, user-interface

I made a GUI contain some label. Once I execute this code in other computer or notebook, the location of those label changed. How do I make the location can be same no matter the display that I execute the code?

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form             = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize  = '578,400'
$Form.text        = "Form"
$Form.BackColor   = "#c1daf7"
$Form.TopMost     = $false
$Form.WindowState = 'Maximized'

$Label1           = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label1.text      = "UNDER PROCESS"
$Label1.AutoSize  = $true
$Label1.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(600, 300)
$Label1.Font      = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,30,style=Bold,Underline'
$Label1.ForeColor = "#d0021b"

$Label2           = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label2.text      = "WAITING"
$Label2.AutoSize  = $true
$Label2.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(770, 500)
$Label2.Font      = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,20,style=Bold'
$Label2.ForeColor = "#fb0505"

$Form.controls.AddRange(@($Label1, $Label2))

[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

### UPDATED

I updated my code with a full code.
I tried this but it return me error:

```
Exception calling "ShowDialog" with "0" argument(s): "Form that is already visible cannot be displayed as a modal dialog box. Set the form's visible property to false before calling showDialog."



 Param (   
        [string]$Path = '*.*',
        [string]$MaxAttempts = 5
    ) 

    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

    # set things up for the timer
    $script:nAttempts = 0
    $timer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer
    $timer.Interval = 1000  # 1 second
    $timer.Add_Tick({
        $global:Result = $null
        $script:nAttempts++
        $file = Get-Item -Path $Path
        if ($file) {
            $global:Result = [PSCustomObject]@{
                Exists   = $true
                FileName = $file.FullName
                Attempts = $script:nAttempts
            }
            $timer.Dispose()
            $Form.Close()
        }
        elseif ($script:nAttempts -ge $MaxAttempts) {
            $global:Result = [PSCustomObject]@{
                Exists   = $false
                FileName = ''
                Attempts = $script:nAttempts
            }
            $timer.Dispose()
            $Form.Close()
        }
    })

    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

    $Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
    $Form.ClientSize                 = '617,418'
    $Form.text                       = "Auto"
    $Form.BackColor                  = "#8b572a"
    $Form.TopMost                    = $false
    $Form.WindowState                = 'Maximized'

    $Label1                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
    $Label1.text                     = "UNDER AUTOMATION PROCESS"
    $Label1.AutoSize                 = $true
    $Label1.width                    = 25
    $Label1.height                   = 10
    $Label1.Anchor                   = 'top,right,bottom,left'

    $Label1.ForeColor                = "#ffffff"
    $Label1.Anchor                   = "None"
    $Label1.TextAlign                = "MiddleCenter"

    $Label2                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
    $Label2.text                     = "Waiting for the job..."
    $Label2.AutoSize                 = $true
    $Label2.width                    = 25
    $Label2.height                   = 10

    $Label2.ForeColor                = "#ffffff"
    $Label2.Anchor                   = "None"
    $Label2.TextAlign                = "MiddleCenter"

    $Form.controls.AddRange(@($Label1,$Label2))

    [void]$Form.Show()
    Write-Host $Form.Height
    Write-Host $Form.Width

    $Label1.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(($Form.Width*0.35), ($Form.Height*0.4))
    $Label2.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(($form.Width*0.43), ($Form.Height*0.5))

    $L_S = (($Form.Width/2) - ($Form.Height / 2)) / 15
    $L_S
    $Label1.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif, $L_S, style=Bold"
    $Label2.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif, $L_S, style=Bold"

    $Form.controls.AddRange(@($Label1,$Label2))
    # start the timer as soon as the dialog is visible
    $Form.Add_Shown({ $timer.Start() })

    [void]$Form.ShowDialog()

    # clean up when done
    $Form.Dispose()
```

I updated my code, I tried this, but it still return me an error. Anyone can help me to fix it please. Thanks

### Updated 2nd

```
Param (   
    [string]$Path = '*.*',
    [string]$MaxAttempts = 5
) 

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

# set things up for the timer
$script:nAttempts = 0
$timer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer
$timer.Interval = 1000  # 1 second
$timer.Add_Tick({
    $global:Result = $null
    $script:nAttempts++
    $file = Get-Item -Path $Path
    if ($file) {
        $global:Result = [PSCustomObject]@{
            Exists   = $true
            FileName = $file.FullName
            Attempts = $script:nAttempts
        }
        $timer.Dispose()
        $Form.Close()
    }
    elseif ($script:nAttempts -ge $MaxAttempts) {
        $global:Result = [PSCustomObject]@{
            Exists   = $false
            FileName = ''
            Attempts = $script:nAttempts
        }
        $timer.Dispose()
        $Form.Close()
    }
})

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
# $Form.ClientSize                 = '617,418'
$Form.text                       = "AutoGM"
$Form.BackColor                  = "#9b9b9b"
$Form.TopMost                    = $false
$Form.Width                      = [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::PrimaryMonitorSize.Width
$Form.Height                     = [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::PrimaryMonitorSize.Height

$FontSize                        = ($Form.Width / 100) + ($Form.Height/100) + 5
$Label1                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label1.text                     = "UNDER PROCESS"
$Label1.AutoSize                 = $true
# $Label1.width                    = 25
# $Label1.height                   = 10
$Label1.Anchor                   = "None"
$Label1.Location                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(($form.Width*0.3), ($Form.Height*0.3))
$Label1.Font                     = "Microsoft Sans Serif,$FontSize,style=Bold"
$Label1.ForeColor                = "#000000"

$Label2                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label2.text                     = "Waiting..."
$Label2.AutoSize                 = $true
# $Label2.width                    = 25
# $Label2.height                   = 10
$Label2.Location                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(($form.Width*0.4), ($Form.Height*0.4))
$Label2.Anchor                   = "None"
$Label2.Font                     = "Microsoft Sans Serif,$FontSize"
$Label2.ForeColor                = "#000000"

$img = [System.Drawing.Image]::Fromfile(".\img.png")
$pictureBox = new-object Windows.Forms.PictureBox
$pictureBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(($form.Width*0.45), ($Form.Height*0.5))
$pictureBox.Width = $Form.Size.Width / 5
$pictureBox.Height = $Form.Size.Height / 5
$pictureBox.Image = $img
$form.controls.add($pictureBox)
$Form.controls.AddRange(@($Label1,$Label2))

# Write-Host $Form.Height
# Write-Host $Form.Width

# $Label1.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(($Form.Width*0.35), ($Form.Height*0.4))
# $Label2.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(($form.Width*0.43), ($Form.Height*0.5))

# $L_S = (($Form.Width/2) - ($Form.Height / 2)) / 15
# $Label1.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif, $L_S, style=Bold"
# $Label2.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif, $L_S, style=Bold"

# $Form.controls.AddRange(@($Label1,$Label2))
# start the timer as soon as the dialog is visible
$Form.Add_Shown({ $timer.Start() })
[void]$Form.ShowDialog()

# clean up when done
$Form.Dispose()
```

Comment: It may depends on resolution of the other computer, so it looks like it moved to different location.. Just print the location on display so you can get the idea..

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Niraj it depends on the resolution of the monitor being used so instead ask yourself where do you want it to show? in mid-mid? mid-left? this can be achieved using some math, see below for a simple example, it uses the $form width en height to calculate the correct position for the labels.

```
$Label1.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(($form.Width*0.5), ($Form.Height*0.5))
$Label2.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(($form.Width*0.5), ($Form.Height*0.4))
```

Comment: Hi @SteloNLD , the problem is, how do I use form.width and height instead of `$Form.WindowState = 'Maximized'`

Comment: If you dont want to use `$Form.WindowState = 'Maximized'` but still want both the form and the labels to be in the center that's also posible but then you need to also make the form position, height and width based on a percentage of the screen resolution, see below for a way to get the screen resolution: `[System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::PrimaryMonitorSize.Width; [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::PrimaryMonitorSize.Height`

Comment: Hi @SteloNLD, I tried this way, but i still found in the some screen the size is not change consider of the screen resolution. I put the code in the   updated 2nd